# A Way To Count Result Based on Date

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT
    a.OrderSuffix AS 'OrderSuffix',
    COUNT(1) AS 'CountNew'
FROM
    dbo.Orders AS a,
    dbo.OrderStatus AS b
WHERE
    b.Status = 'Finished' AND
    a.OrderSuffix IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ')
GROUP BY
    a.OrderSuffix
```

For this query above, I can get all total rows count for each order suffix. Is there a way to include a date as well?

E.g. I want to count all rows of 'ABC' whose dateField is greater than specifiedDate.

Comment: I believe you are missing a link between [Orders] and [OrderStatus], usually it should be a column named [OrderID]. Anyway, put your table structure here and you will get better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter rows before you aggregate, you can just put it in your `WHERE` clause.

If you want the comparison to be based on the aggregate (e.g. groups with, say, a max dateField greater than some value) you can use the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I need to put `HAVING` for each `OrderSuffix`. However, I can only put one `HAVING` condition for one `OrderSuffix` in one query.

Comment: My application has something to do with notifying a user. with new data (how many data were recently added). I have to count all new rows for each Order Suffix where each OrderSuffix's date is greater than specified date.

Currently, what I have done, is I created a for loop. There are 200 + order suffixes but I only limited it to 10 because of the slow ness in fetching data.

ANd I dont think for looping an SQL query for each order suffix is a great idea.

Comment: `WITH
cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        a.OrderSuffix AS 'OrderSuffix',
  a.UpdatedAt AS 'UpdatedAt'
    FROM
        dbo.Orders AS a,
        dbo.OrderStatus AS b
    WHERE
        b.Status = 'Finished' AND
        a.OrderSuffix IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ')
    GROUP BY
        a.OrderSuffix,
  a.UpdatedAt
 HAVING a.UpdatedAt > <date> AND b.OrderSuffix = '000'
)
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS TotalCount
FROM
    cte`

I can only add one `HAVING`.

Comment: Or maybe I should just use UNION ALL for these 10 SQL queries?

Comment: Can you attach what you expect the output to look like?